# Update method in Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet, pyopengl

I am new to pyglet and I have a question about the image on the screen update. Necessary each time the mouse pressed to change the count, but I have all the time is zero, where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

```
from pyglet.window import mouse
from pyglet import *
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)
n = 0
label = pyglet.text.Label(str(n), x = window.width/2, y = window.width/2 )

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        global n
        n += 1

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

def update():
    pass

pyglet.app.run()
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/30.0)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create again the label in order to change its value (or better modify the `label.text` attribute)! Actually you didn't pass `n` to `pyglet.text.Label` but a string created "on the fly" containing that value.

```
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        global n
        n += 1
        label.text = str(n)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I take care with the `label` , but how in the method `on_mouse_press` I can create a new primitive like `GL_POINTS` with the coordinates `(x, y)`?

Comment: @Artur123 I'm afraid I can't help you with that, I never used Pyglet nor OpenGL.